# Vlsub extension for vlc issue

Tags: 14.04, vlc

On freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04, with freshly installed vlc, the vlsub extension launches a window when no file is open. Once I open any video, the extension does not open the vlsub window.

Tried with the master-daily ppa,

Tried with vlsub-extension in the ppa, &

Tried with manual install.

None of these worked
Always the same issue: the vlsub window refuses to open once any video is played.

Has anyone an idea to fix it?

Comment: The command for the system wide install is not working because permission is denied so I used 'gksudo nautilus' to copy-paste the lua file manually and...finally this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

According to their [official website](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/VLSub+0.9.11?content=148752):

> VLSub is not working with Vlc 2.1.x on any platform because the lua
>   "net" module needed to interact with opensubtitles has been removed in
>   this release for the extensions. Works with Vlc 2.2 on mac and linux.

Too bad Ubuntu has 2.1.x. So, first step is to get a more recent version of VLC:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

At the time of writing, the VLSub plugin in the Ubuntu repositories (0.9.10-1) does not search for subtitles, and the latest version from GitHub has problems opening the subtitle once downloaded. So, I created a fork that actually works (tested on VLC 2.2.0~~git20140609+r57027+123~ubuntu14.04.1 and all later releases, no problems so far):

```
wget https://github.com/kraxor/vlsub/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd vlsub-master
```

To install locally, type:

```
cp vlsub.lua ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
```

Or install system-wide:

```
sudo cp vlsub.lua /usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/
```

And you're done. Enjoy.

Comment: How to Upgrade to VLC 2.2.0 (Stable) in Ubuntu 14.04: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/02/upgrade-vlc-2-2-0-stable-ubuntu-14-04/